# GLB object not loading on flutter windows

Tags: flutter, dart, 3d-model

I'm using `model_viewer_plus` and I have a problem showing the model file.

I've cloned this (repo)[https://github.com/omchiii/model_viewer_plus.dart] but it gave me this error on windows:

`Unsupported operation: Trying to use the default webview implementation for TargetPlatform.windows but there isn't a default one`

any ideas

I've tried the repo and it didn't worked either.

Answer (score 0):

The [package](https://pub.dev/packages/model_viewer_plus) that you are using(model viewer plus) doesn't support adding GLB objects because the package only support `Android`, `iOS` and `Web` platform. But it seems like you are running on windows platform. So, it throws error that it can't get the `WebView` implementation, because it is only available on android, iOS, web and not on windows.